# How to create a third table based on two other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of Colour names

```
Red
Yellow
Green
Purple
```

I also have a Table of Coloured Tops

```
RedandGreen
Red
YellowandRedandGreen
Violet
```

What I want to do is create a third table where if I select Red it will show me all the tops with Red in and the other thing I want it to do is if I Select Purple it needs to bring back Violet.

Is this possible?

Thanks

W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion, is not necessary create a third table to show your informations.
If you link both tables using a correct foreign key, your job will work.

See:

```
create table color
(
id_color int not null,
ds_color varchar(50) null,
primary key (id_color)
)

create table color_tops
(
id_color int not null,
id_colortop int not null,
ds_colortop varchar(50) null,
primary key (id_colortop),
foreign key (id_color) references color(id_color)
)

select color.ds_color,
       color_tops.ds_colortops
from   color
       inner join color on (color.id_color = color_tops.ds_colortops)
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any way to do this for the Purple = Violet than have another lookup table. For instance how is the system supposed to know that Light Blue and Cyan are the same color?

```
ColorShades
PrimaryColor|Shade
Purple|Purple
Purple|Violet
Blue|Blue
Blue|Cyan
...

Tops
TopColors
RedandGreen
Red
YellowandRedandGreen
Violet

SELECT TopColors
FROM Tops, ColorShades
WHERE ColorShades.PrimaryColor = Purple
AND Tops.TopColors like '%ColorShades.Shade%'
```

So you could have a table that translates various colors down to a couple of tables that you allow.

Assuming you're using this for a dropdown selection, you could make the source of that selection be `SELECT DISTINCT PrimaryColor FROM ColorShades` and have only one color definition table.

Comment: How do I create this look up table?

Comment: MS SQL has some easy to use visual tools for creating tables.  Try Microsoft SQL Management Studio.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961  Or you can write SQL to create a table: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp and populate it: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: Note this kind of text matching is easy to create and maintain, but is slower than the ID based answers some others have provided.  An advanced hybrid solution would be to have this easy to edit text matching table, then periodically run a query to build an ID matching table to match up products.  Then the actual interface would use the faster ID matching table.  The only downsides are A) it requires a decent understanding of what you're doing, and B) new products won't show up in color searches until the periodic query is run.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, but it's going to be horribly impractical. Especially when you start adding more and more shades of e.g. purple, like mauve, lavender, Lilac, etc. It's not a good idea.

What you will have to do is create a third table called colors_to_tops and when entering data, assign each top to every colour you want it returned for.

Colors table

```
id|color
--------
 1|Red
 2|Yellow
 3|Green
 4|Purple
```

Colored Tops

```
id|TopName
--------------
 1|RedandGreen
 2|Red
 3|YellowandRedandGreen
 4|Violet
```

colors_to_tops

```
id|colorID|topID
----------------
 1|      1|    1
 2|      1|    2
 3|      1|    3
 4|      2|    3
 5|      3|    1
 6|      3|    3
 7|      4|    4
```

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ct.* FROM
    ColoredTops AS ct
LEFT JOIN
    Colors_To_Tops AS ctt
ON
    ct.id = ctt.topID
LEFT JOIN
    Colors AS c
ON
    ctt.colorID = c.id

WHERE c.color = @color
```

Comment: Hi Juann that's exactly what I want but how does the colors_to_tops know what color ID to use what is the SQL?

Comment: Added the SQL to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a join table:

**create tables with ids**

```
CREATE TABLE colour ( 
 id int primary key,
 colour varchar(10)
);

create table tops (
  id int primary key,
  tops varchar(50)
  );
```

**create a join table to relate them**

```
create table top_colours
(
  top_id int, 
  colour_id int
)
```

**add your data**

```
insert into tops(id,tops)
select 
1, 'RedandGreen'
union select 
2, 'Red'
union select 
3, 'YellowandRedandGreen'
union select 
4, 'Violet';


insert into colour(id,colour)
select 1, 'Red'
union select 
2, 'Yellow'
union select 
3,'Green'
union select 
4,'Purple';

insert into top_colours(top_id,colour_id)
select 1,1 union
select 1,3 union
select 2,1 union
select 3,2 union
select 3,1 union
select 3,3 union
select 4,4;
```

**ask away**

```
select distinct  tops.* from tops 
join top_colours tc on tc.top_id =  tops.id
join colour c on c.id = tc.colour_id 
where c.colour = 'red' ; 

select distinct  tops.* from tops 
join top_colours tc on tc.top_id =  tops.id
join colour c on c.id = tc.colour_id 
where c.colour = 'purple' ;
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/71c91/3)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to create another table out of it, but would something like this work:

```
select c.color, t.colors
from color c 
  left join tops t on t.colors like '%' + replace(c.color,'Purple','Violet') + '%'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90fdf3/3)

Then you can add your `WHERE` criteria as needed -- `where c.color = 'Red'` for example.

*--EDIT*

As others have suggested, consider using a lookup table for your colors.  Something like this:

```
select c.color, t.colors
from color c 
  left join coloralias ca on c.color = ca.color
  left join tops t on  t.colors like '%' + c.color + '%' or t.colors like '%' + ca.alias + '%'
```

[Another Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/091eb/2)

Comment: select c.ColoursName, s.SilksName
from [dbo].[Colours] c 
  left join [dbo].[Silks] s on s.SilksName like '%' + replace(c.ColoursName,'Purple','Violet') + '%'

How do I write your query without referring to purple violet at this stage?

Comment: @wafw1971 -- if you don't want to hard code purple=violet, you'll need another table -- a lookup table as others have suggested.

Comment: Im really new to SQL so how would I create a look up table? And how would I link it to the above query

Comment: @wafw1971 -- no worries -- see edits above.  Added a fiddle demo as well.  Best regards.